# entity-framework throws error only while publish in single file

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have a .net core 3.1 WPF sample project with the entity-framework core&sqlite.

Here is the code in Mainwindow.XAML:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace WpfApp1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }



        public ObservableCollection<string> ObjectList { get; set; } 

        private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                Database.AppDBContext Context = new Database.AppDBContext();
                ObjectList = new ObservableCollection<string>(Context.TestTable.Select(X => X.name));
                this.DataContext = this;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the code of XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800" Loaded="Window_Loaded">
    <Grid>
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding ObjectList}">
            
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Here is the code of database:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;

namespace WpfApp1.Database
{
    public class AppDBContext : DbContext
    {
        public virtual DbSet<TestModel> TestTable { get; set; }
        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            string Path = System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"\database.db";
            if (File.Exists(Path))
            {
                optionsBuilder.UseSqlite("Data Source=" + Path);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the code of database model:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Text;

namespace WpfApp1.Database
{
    public class TestModel
    {
        [Key]
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

PS: I placed the database.db in the same folder as my program file.

If I debug the program or publish it without `Produce Single File`, all works well.

However, after I published it in a single file, it runs with an error above:
[image]

[image]

What's wrong with it? And how can I solve this? Thank you.

Comment: Have you debugged your program and checked that OnConfiguring will be called when you create a new DbContext? I expect it won't and you have to provide something like DbContextOptions or something to your DbContext when creating it. You should read the docs about how to create a DbContext.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved.

`System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory` doesn't get the right directory of the program.

It seems the Single File program will extract all the files into a temporary folder and run.

The `System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory` is just getting the path of the temporary folder but not the program folder.

As https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/single-file said, I should use `AppContext.BaseDirectory` instead of it.